# AMD Propietary drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, 64-bit, jockey

Is it safe to install AMD Propietary drivers with Additional drivers feature? Arent they outdated? The one with (post release updates) tag fails after download. I tried to install the drivers using Terminal and drivers directly from AMD but it didnt work because it failed when I was trying to make .deb from .run .

EDIT: Ubuntu is choppy. I thought it was only for HD video, but exactly the same result with 240p. Desktop is smooth, I have the same results with Ubuntu 2D. I dont know what is wrong with Ubuntu, I remember I was using Ubuntu 10.10 and it was performing better than Windows. Now when I compare Ubuntu 12 04 to WIndows 8, Ubuntu fails in performance. (both 64 bit). I also tried playing Minecraft and same lags on low settings and on high settings. THis looks more like CPU performance is low. When running Virtualbox Ubuntu was stuck for hours then system crashed. All apps preinstalled in Ubuntu 12 04 DVD version are unstable, calc crashed LOL, software center crashes a lot. IDK what to do with that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed AMD Propietary drivers with Additional drivers feature, believe me they are too good. Ubuntu proprietary drivers for graphic cards are not that good. for installing the AMD Proprietary drivers follow this link: 
[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513)

hope this is helpful.